AWS data exports adds and updates records for past dates and months
Currently i have multiple data exports. The problem is when the new month begins every day AWS adds the values of some records for the previous month. Is there some kind of documentation or information about this behaviour because it seems very non deterministic.
For example if today is fourth of april the export will add the new data for today and add data for march.
In some places i saw that 14 days ago from today but im not really sure.

This is how you should do it:

Data table content settings: CUR 2.0
Additional export content: Include resource IDs
Time granularity: Daily


Then you go:

Compression type and file format: Parquet or CSV, you decide that
File versioning: OVERWRITE (this is the important part for you)


Now that you have OVERWRITE a new file will be generated every day and will overwrite the old one. This will happen till next month where a new folder with a new file will be created for the next month.
Delete or turn off any other export. You don't need monthly export any more.
